# search result returning the index value in angular js issue

Tags: python, angularjs

Angular  **JS**   search result came only indexing format issues

[image: in an image showing the search result indexing fist and then get the result from the local storage]

Comment: How are you using the return data?

Comment: $scope.search_advertisers = function (query) {
            $scope.searchdata=query;

            $timeout(function () {
            $scope.myPromise = $http.get(envConfig.serverName + "api/advertisers?user_id=" + $scope.user_id + "&sid=" + $cookies.ANsid + '&advertiser_campaigns_data='+ true + '&search=' + $scope.searchdata
                    , {cache: true})
                    .success(function (response) {
                        $scope.result = response.advertiser_campaigns_count;

                    });

                    },4000);
        };

Comment: i used to get the data from using api and in HTML code    <div ng-show="query != ''" class="dashboard-clients">
                <div ng-repeat="(key, data) in result">
                    <a ng-click="selectClients(key)">{{key}}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

Comment: first its showing indexing i just saw the console in KEY value its showing the index value  and then get the search result

Comment: Use the {{data}} instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue on HTML code,instead of {{key}} use {{data}} or {{data.yourVariableName}}

```
<div ng-show="query != ''" class="dashboard-clients"> <div ng-repeat="(key, data) in result"> <a ng-click="selectClients(key)">{{data.yourVariableName}}</a> </div> </div> </form> </div>
```

Comment: i have add {{data}} instead of key indexing remove but search is not working now

Comment: Can you give result array?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should use `{{data}}` instead of `{{key}}`:

```
<div ng-show="query != ''" class="dashboard-clients"> <div ng-repeat="(key, data) in result"> <a ng-click="selectClients(key)">{{data}}</a> </div> </div> </form> </div>
```